# How to create a nested $resource - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to create a nested `$resource`. I have come up with the following, which seems to work..ish, but seems awfully wrong. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

My data structure is:

```
allData = [{
    id:1,
    info:'someinfo',
    foo :'foobar',
    bar : {...},
    baz : [{...}, {...}, {...}]
    },
    {id:2, ...},
    {id:3, ...}
    ];
```

I would like each object in `allData` to be a `$resource` object. I also want each object in the `baz` array to be a `$resource` object as well.

What I have come up with is:

```
var InfoService = angular.module('InfoServices', ['ngResource']);

// The inner resource
InfoService.factory('Baz', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      var baz = $resource('/server/baz', {});

      // custom baz methods
      baz.prototype.getBaz = function() {};

      return baz;
}]);

// Outer resource
InfoService.factory('Info', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      var info = $resource('/server/info', {});

      // custom data methods
      info.prototype.getInfoStats = function() {};

      return info;
}]);

// Array of resources.
InfoService.factory('AllInfo', ['$resource','Info', 'Baz',
function($resource,Info,Baz) {
  var resource = $resource('/server/allinfo', {},
                          { query : {
                              method:'get',
                              isArray:true,
                              transformResponse:function(data) {
                                var allinfo = JSON.parse(data);

                                for (var i=0;i<allinfo.length;i++) {
                                  allinfo[i] = new Info(allinfo[i]);

                                  for (var j=0;j<allinfo[i].baz.length;j++) {
                                    allinfo[i].baz[j] = new Baz(allinfo[i].baz[j]);
                                  }

                                }
                                return allinfo;
                              }
                          });
  return resource;
}]);
```

Like I said..seems awfully wrong, what's the Angular way to achieving the above?

Answer (score 1):

```
InfoService.factory('resources', function($resource) {
    return {
        id: $resource(...),
        info: $resource(...),
        //...and so on... 
    }
})

//example usage
InfoService.controller('ctrl', function(resources) {
    this.id = resources.id.query();
})
```

If you want to make everything a resource, this is the way to go. But ask yourself...is it really necessary to make every attribute a separate resource? What about grouping in a resource all attributes that are strictly related? I ask because I am not sure of what these data rapresent to you.

Comment: I don't necessarily need every attribute a `resource`, but each object in the array would be nice. Because then in my controller I could go `$scope.info[0].baz[1].$save` and wouldn't have to send the entire `$scope.info` object over the wire. Does that make sense? I'm new to Angular, so I'm struggling with it as you can see. I will try your suggestion and see if it works for me.

Comment: Well, it really depends on how much data are you saving, how frequently, and also what is the target (desktop or mobile). I know that the approaches could be very different depending on these factors. Still, I have been programming webapps only for a few months now, so I am a newcomer as well, I don't feel like I could give a really reliable advice in that sense :)